# Constructing a particular transitive subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Using Cayley’s theorem, I want to construct a transitive subgroup of $S_6$ which is
isomorphic to $S_3$. I've been struggling with group theory rather a lot, and I find this particular problem to be very difficult.
Cayley's Theorem states that: "Every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_G$". What exactly does this imply for the problem that I want to solve? I know what a transitive group is, but I don't know how Cayley's Theorem comes into this problem.
On a related note, does one develop an intuition for group theory with enough practice? I've had enormous issues with the general abstractions so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bad idea to make this abstract algebra less *abstract*.
The subgroup of $S_6$ generated by $\sigma=(1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)$ and $\tau=(1\,4)(2\,5)(3\,6)$ is the symmetry group of a triangular prism, and it is pretty obviously transitive and isomorphic to $S_3$.

[image]

Comment: You are right, the graphical depiction does make it rather obvious. I guess that might be an approach that I should try in the future. Thank you. The actual subgroup would have to include the unit element (1), though, right?

Comment: @user569579: $\sigma^3=\tau^2=(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There are six elements of $S_3$, and the elements in $S_3$ canonically act on these by ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean with "canonically acting on"? I am not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: @user569579 You can swap "canonically" with "naturally". You want a subgroup of $S_6$, so you need a set of six elements you can act on (permute). $S_3$ has six elements. Now, here it may be difficult to keep everything straight: You have the _set_ $S_3$, and the _group_ $S_3$ acting on that set in some way. What is the most natural way you can think of to combine an element from the group $S_3$ with an element from the set $S_3$ to make an element of the set $S_3$?

Comment: I would say by acting on it with the unit element $e$, so that the element remains the same. That way, all the elements are preserved.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not transitive. In what other way can you combine two elements of $S_3$ to make a new element of $S_3$?

Comment: I believe by acting on it with a cycle that has the same length as the element. Perhaps I'm just talking nonsense now, though... Like I said, I find this topic very difficult.

Comment: "left multiplication". maybe that's where @Arthur is trying to get you at?

Comment: @tangentbundle That's the one. Or right, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

(Multiplication is right-to-left.)

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, all the pointwise stabilizers are trivial, so every non-identity permutation of the sought subgroup, say $K$, moves all the elements of $\{1,\dots,6\}$. Therefore, the elements of order $3$ and $2$ which generate $K$ must have cycle type $(3,3)$ and $(2,2,2)$, respectively. Choose as the former $\sigma=(123)(456)$, whence $\sigma^2=(132)(465)$. Now, let's look for a suitable element of order $2$ and cycle type $(2,2,2)$, say $\tau=(1i)(jk)(lm)$, considered that a presentation for $K\cong S_3\cong D_3$ is:
$$K=\langle\sigma,\tau\mid(\tau\sigma)^2=()\rangle\tag1$$
We get $i\ne2,3$, because otherwise $\tau\sigma$ or $\sigma\tau$, respectively, fixes $1$. So, let's take $\tau=(14)(2k)(lm)$. Clearly $k\ne 3$, because otherwise $\tau\sigma$ fixes $2$. Therefore, $\tau=(14)(25)(36)$ or $\tau=(14)(26)(35)$. But the latter only fulfils $(1)$, and hence a suitable $K$ is:
$$K=\langle(123)(456),(14)(26)(35)\rangle$$

Answer (score 0):

> Using Cayley’s theorem, I want to construct a transitive subgroup of $S_6$
> which is isomorphic to $S_3$.

So thoroughly formulated, I see no shortcuts to the complete routine.

Cayley's embedding $\varphi\colon S_3\hookrightarrow S_{S_3}$ is defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&()&&\mapsto ()\circ\_ \\
&(12)&&\mapsto (12)\circ\_ \\
&(13)&&\mapsto (13)\circ\_ \\
&(23)&&\mapsto (23)\circ\_ \\
&(123)&&\mapsto (123)\circ\_ \\
&(132)&&\mapsto (132)\circ\_ \\
\end{alignat}
To embed the transitive subgroup $(S_3\cong)\varphi(S_3)\le S_{S_3}$ into $S_6$, you've got to choose any amongst the $6!$ bijections $S_3\to \{1,\dots,6\}$, say for example $f$ defined by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&()&&\mapsto 1 \\
&(12)&&\mapsto 2 \\
&(13)&&\mapsto 3 \\
&(23)&&\mapsto 4 \\
&(123)&&\mapsto 5 \\
&(132)&&\mapsto 6 \\
\tag1
\end{alignat}
Then, the isomorphism $\psi_f\colon S_{S_3}\to S_6$, defined by $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$, does the job. For example:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(()\circ\_))[1] &= (f(()\circ\_)) f^{-1})[1] \\
&= f((()\circ\_)(f^{-1}[1])) \\
&= f(()\circ ()) \\
&= f(()) \\
&= 1
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(()\circ\_))[2] &= (f(()\circ\_)) f^{-1})[2] \\
&= f((()\circ\_)(f^{-1}[2])) \\
&= f(()\circ (12)) \\
&= f((12)) \\
&= 2
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(()\circ\_))[3] &= (f(()\circ\_)) f^{-1})[3] \\
&= f((()\circ\_)(f^{-1}[3])) \\
&= f(()\circ (13)) \\
&= f((13)) \\
&= 3
\end{alignat}
*etc.*. So, finally:
$$\psi_f(()_{S_3}\circ\_)=()_{S_6}$$
Likewise, you will find:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\psi_f((12)\circ\_) &&=(12)(36)(45) \\
&\psi_f((13)\circ\_) &&=(13)(25)(46) \\
&\psi_f((23)\circ\_) &&=(14)(26)(35) \\
&\psi_f((123)\circ\_) &&=(156)(234) \\
&\psi_f((132)\circ\_) &&=(165)(243) \\
\end{alignat}
whence: $$S_3\stackrel{\psi_f\varphi}{\cong}\{(),(12)(36)(45),(13)(25)(46),(14)(26)(35),(156)(234),(165)(243)\}\le S_6$$
Other choices of the bijection $f$ in $(1)$ will lead to different transitive subgroups of $S_6$ isomorphic to $S_3$.

(Btw, for $f$ defined by $()\mapsto 1$, $(123)\mapsto 2$, $(132)\mapsto 3$, $(12)\mapsto 4$, $(13)\mapsto 5$, $(23)\mapsto 6$, you will get the subgroup as in other answer of mine.)